# How can internal energy be expressed as a function of any two of $p, v, T$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature, volume

In the book of Irey, *Theormodynamics*, the author states that (while talking about single phase substances)

> For a simple compressible media, we may choose our measurable
>   independent variables any two of $p, v, T$.The traditional choice for internal energy is temperature and specific volume, $u = u(T,v)$.

However, this statement is as if it just falls from the sky; he does not provide any argument why $u$ can be expressed as a function of any two of those variable, nor does he give any argument about the relationship of one of those variables to another two.

**Question:**

I'm looking for an explanation about the concerns that I raised above.

**Edit:**

As @SolarMike pointed out, the author explicitly consider gaseous substances in the above comment; however, later he also defines 
$$Z = \frac{ pv}{RT } = Z (p, T) ,$$
i.e knowing $p,T$ allows you to calculate $Z$, and then you can find $v$, but he still does not give any argument why $Z = Z (p,T)$. As far as I can see, Charles's law, and the other two law accompanying it are for ideal gases, but we are not woking with ideal gases, yet.

Comment: Just like Ohm's law, knowing two defines the third...

Comment: @SolarMike I got it, but why and how ? what is that relationship, i.e if I give any two of them what is the third one in terms of the first two ?

Comment: So what relates p, v & T - have you looked at Boyles or Charles laws and the universal gas constant?

Comment: @SolarMike The author talks about a single phase substances in general, not just gases. As far as I know, those law valid only for gases.

Comment: Is not the statement "compressible media" - I'm assuming "compressile" was your typing...

Comment: @SolarMike You are right, actually. I've noticed that part right now. However, do those laws have versions when the gases are not perfect ?

Comment: R the universal gas constant does have a specific value for an ideal gas... You might find this helps : https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-gas-constant-r-604477  I always remember pv = nRT...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, please see my edit also.

Comment: If you read the link I provided, you should find it covers what you ask... ie pv = ZRT is equivalent to pv = nRT...

Comment: @SolarMike I actually read it, and after your last comment I re-read it, but I still cannot see anything related to $pv = ZRT$ being equivalent to $pv=nRT$. Plus, how can that be true ? it would imply that $n  = Z$, but the book provided lots of explicit experimental data where $Z \not = 1$.

Comment: Please tell me where I said n=1?

Comment: @SolarMike You didn't, but we can take one mole of gas, and measure its $Z$ value.

Comment: I think you might have to go back to the beginning of the chapter, what happened to R and v in that expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component that you're missing is that the various state variables of a system are related by the **equation of state** for the system, which reduces the number of degrees of freedom by one. For ideal gases, this is the ideal gas law; for real gases, something like the van der Waals equation serves as an equation of state. For solids and liquids, there are various forms of the equation of state that vary in the kind of behavior they're meant to model best; for a short sampling of them, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state#Equations_of_state_for_solids_and_liquids.

Comment: I see, a constraint exists between the generalised coordinates, but what is it ? depends on the systems, and it might not turn out to be as simple as the ideal gas law.

Comment: @onurcanbektas There's a different "true" equation of state for every state of matter, and even then, there are many different models for the equations of state of different materials depending on which macroscopic properties are important to model.